# Generic buildList function with @resultBuilder

Tags: swift

Is it possible to have a generic `buildList` function that works with all kind of elements?

```swift
let filter = Filter(name: "John")
let conditions = buildList<(User) -> Bool> {
  if let name = filter.name {
    { $0.name == name }
  }
  if let maxAge = filter.maxAge {
    { $0.age <= maxAge }
  }
}
let filtered = users.filter { user in
  conditions.allSatisfy { $0(user) }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something similar to Kotlin's [`buildList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html) function?

Comment: Exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than result builders, I would just write a function like this:

```
func buildArray<T>(_ type: T.Type = T.self, block: (inout [T]) -> Void) -> [T] {
    var array = [T]()
    block(&array)
    return array
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = buildArray(Int.self) {
    $0.append(1)
    $0.append(2)
    $0.append(3)
    // you can put whatever control flow statements you need in here...
}
```

If you really hate writing `$0.append` all the time, you can use a result builder:

```
@resultBuilder
struct ArrayBuilder<T> {
    typealias Component = [T]

    static func buildExpression(_ expression: T) -> Component {
        [expression]
    }

    static func buildBlock(_ components: Component...) -> Component {
        components.flatMap { $0 }
    }

    static func buildArray(_ components: [Component]) -> Component {
        components.flatMap { $0 }
    }

    static func buildOptional(_ component: Component?) -> Component {
        component ?? []
    }

    static func buildEither(first component: Component) -> Component {
        component
    }

    static func buildEither(second component: Component) -> Component {
        component
    }
}
```

Note that this turns all the expressions in the closure into a one-element array. Then concatenates all of them together. I did not benchmark this but I suspect this would cause quite a lot of array allocations. If that is a problem, you can try this other implementation instead:

```
@resultBuilder
struct ArrayBuilder<T> {
    enum Component {
        case array([T]), element(T), nothing
    }
    
    static func buildExpression(_ expression: T) -> Component {
        .element(expression)
    }
    
    static func buildBlock(_ components: Component...) -> Component {
        buildArray(components)
    }
    
    static func buildArray(_ components: [Component]) -> Component {
        var array = [T]()
        for component in components {
            switch component {
            case .array(let a): array.append(contentsOf: a)
            case .element(let t): array.append(t)
            default: break
            }
        }
        return .array(array)
    }
    
    static func buildOptional(_ component: Component?) -> Component {
        component ?? .nothing
    }
    
    static func buildEither(first component: Component) -> Component {
        component
    }
    
    static func buildEither(second component: Component) -> Component {
        component
    }
    
    static func buildFinalResult(_ component: Component) -> [T] {
        switch component {
        case .array(let a): return a
        case .element(let t): return [t]
        default: return []
        }
    }
}
```

This uses an enum for the `Component` type, so that the expressions in the closure can be turned into `.element(expr)` instead, avoiding some of the array allocations.

The `buildArray` function can then look like this:

```
func buildArray<T>(_ type: T.Type = T.self, @ArrayBuilder<T> block: () -> [T]) -> [T] {
    block()
}
```

Unlike the first `buildArray`, Swift is usually able to infer the type of the array based on the expressions in the builder:

```
let array = buildArray {
    1
    2
    3
    // you can use if, switch, and for statements in here
}
```